Cartoon based on '1001 nights' from 80/90's
Back in early 2000's there was a dubbed cartoon aired on Russian television.
Here are the things I remember about this show:

The central characters are noble woman (princess, maybe?) named Shahrazad and djinn named Tille (or something similar). The woman is in her mid-20's, she is dressed in eastern (arabesque I'd say) dress. The djinn looks like a teenage boy, he is dressed in bloomers, sleeveless shirt and turban;
The cartoon is heavily based on '1001 nights' stories;
I'm not sure when it was produced, but I've seen this cartoon in 2001/2002, so I think it was from 90's, maybe 80's;
I'm pretty sure it's a Turkish cartoon;

I remember one of the episodes:
The woman and the djinn stayed at the teahouse when some King (pretty sure it was a king since his son was a prince) with his guards comes in after a long road. He talks to the woman and tells her that he is looking for his son. A long time ago he was foretold that he will go blind when he sees his son, so he sent him away as soon as boy was born. About 20 years later the King decided to find his lost son, so now he travels the lands.
The King tastes some sweets, likes them and asks for a cook to thank him. The cook comes, and Kings goes blind, because the cook happens to be his son. 
Then the woman and the djinn team up with Kings son to find some kind of magical flower to cure Kings blindness.
Can you help me find it?

please put a more descriptive title in this question

@Luciano - any suggestions? "Turkish (maybe) cartoon from 90's (maybe 80's) aired on Russian TV" doesn't sound good.

How about "Cartoon based on 1001 nights from 80/90's" or " 80-90's Turkish cartoon about a king's tale" it doesn't need to be super specific, just anything that is not so generic like "help me identify this cartoon"

You're looking for Princesse Shéhérazade, the french cartoon. Your description reminded me that I also saw this as a kid, but dubbed in my own language.

Accompanied by her beloved Till, who has the power to transform herself, Princess Sheherazade recounts her adventures throughout the world of the Arabian Nights.





Yeah, that's the one.
